# Raspbian shutdown from Windows IoT Core

Tags: uwp, raspbian, windows-10-iot-core

I am building a Windows UWP app in Visual Studio which is running on a Raspberry Pi 3B.  From this I would like to shutdown / reboot another Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.
Is that possible and how? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use a SSH client such as **Chilkat.Ssh** or **Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET** in UWP app to connect to the Raspbian, and then send the shutdown/reboot command( e.g.`sudo shutdown –h now`) to it. Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET if a free library, but Chilkat.Ssh is not. You can find some other SSH libraries which could support .Net Standard 2.0/UAP 10.

**Update:**

The following code snippet is with using Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET library. It works in my UWP app run on Windows IoT Core.

**C#**:

```
    private async void ButtonReboot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,  async () =>
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xx", "xxxxxxx"))
            {
                client.Connect();
                var command = client.CreateCommand("sudo reboot -f");
                var asyncResult = command.BeginExecute();
                var reader = new StreamReader(command.OutputStream);

                while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
                {
                    await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }

                command.EndExecute(asyncResult);

                client.Disconnect();
            }
        });
    }
```

**VB.NET**

```
Private Async Sub ButtonReboot_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    Await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            Async Sub()
                Using sClient = New SshClient("XXX.XXX.XXX", "XX", "XXXX")
                    sClient.Connect()
                    If sClient.IsConnected Then
                        Dim sCommand = sClient.CreateCommand("sudo reboot -f \r\n")
                        Dim asyncResult = sCommand.BeginExecute()
                        Dim reader = New StreamReader(sCommand.OutputStream)

                        While Not asyncResult.IsCompleted
                            Await reader.ReadToEndAsync()
                        End While

                        sCommand.EndExecute(asyncResult)

                        Debug.WriteLine("Reboot")
                        sClient.Disconnect()
                    End If
                End Using
            End Sub)

End Sub
```

Comment: Happy New Year.
Thank you very much for your reply.
Unfortunately, Chilkat is not free. Is there a different solution?

Comment: @henrikl2000, you can use Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET. This is .NET Core / Net Standard 2.0 release of Renci SSH.NET library. I have tested with this library, it works. At first i tried to use SSH.NET, i thought it would support UAP 10.0, but i got the error 'Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification'.

Comment: @henrikl2000, i have updated my response, hope that can help you.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tested Asmodat.Standard.SSH.NET in my UWP code and it works using the IP address or name of the Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi reboots using your example, but my program hangs after sending the ssh command. Do you know a solution to that?

Comment: @henrikl2000, you can use `BeginExecute` method which is asynchronous instead of `RunCommand` method,

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. Now my UWP app doesn’t hang, but sadly the Raspberry Pi doesn’t reboot. Tested with the correct IP address and name. Do you have an idea? By the way I am using VS 2017 and Visual Basic.

Comment: Did you confirm the network, username and password? You can try to use putty tool  to connect with the Raspbian and test the command. The code updated in my response works for me.

Comment: I can login using putty using the same IP, user  and password as in my app.
Here is how I test it with a button click. With RunCommand it works but my app hangs. It's stange isn't it

    Private Sub btnTest3_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnTest3.Click
        Using sClient = New SshClient("192.168.0.181", "pi", "xxxxxx")
            sClient.Connect()

            Dim sCommand = sClient.CreateCommand("sudo reboot -f")
            sCommand.BeginExecute()

            Debug.WriteLine("Reboot")
            sClient.Disconnect()
        End Using
    End Sub

Comment: Yes Private Networks(Client & Server) is enabled. I really wonder why it works for your app and not for mine.

Comment: I think I got it creating a task.
        Await Task.Run(Function() Ssh("192.168.0.181", "pi", "xxxxx")) and in the task using RunCommand

Comment: @henrikl2000, I found that why the code works for me, that is due to there is a breakpoint at the _BeginExecute_ method line. Please refer to the latest update in my response.

Comment: Thank you very Michael for all your help and time. Your updated code works very well. You are brilliant :)